# Secure method using annotations

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I have a page with a form and want to know if it is possible to access it using GET, but only allow logged in users to POST to it.

I know this can be done in security.yml, but am not sure how to do it with annotations.

```
 /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
     * @Method(methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function calculatorAction(Request $request)
    {

        $form=$this->createForm(new CallRequestType(),$callReq=new CallRequest());


        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()){
            //blabla
        }


        return $this->render('MyBundle:Pages:calculator.html.twig', array('form' => $form));
    }
```

This will secure the whole function, but I want to access it, just not POST to it without being logged in. An alternative would be to check if there is a logged in user in the $form->isValid() bracket. But I'm still wondering if it can be done with annotations.

Comment: A little point out of the question: The `@Method` annotation is only considered when an action is annotated with `@Route`.

Comment: Good to know, I didn't know that.

Comment: i suggest you to split in two separate method

Comment: I was thinking the same, but didn't want to. Thought there is an alternative. Guess I'll go with that, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this.

You can allow both method types anonymously, and check just inside the controller to see if the user is authenticated and is POSTing.

*(You don't state which version of symfony you're using, so you might have to substitute the `authorization_checker` (2.8) for the older `security.context` service)*

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 *
 * @Route("/someroute", name="something")
 * @Method(methods={"POST", "GET"})
 */
public function calculatorAction(Request $request)
{

    if ( !$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') && $request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
    }


    $form=$this->createForm(new CallRequestType(),$callReq=new CallRequest());


    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // you also need to check submitted or youll fire the validation on every run through.
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        //blabla
    }


    return $this->render('MyBundle:Pages:calculator.html.twig', array('form' => $form));
}
```

Comment: authorization_checker is available before 2.8, too, but yes, I'm using 2.8. This is what I ended up doing. I was looking for a way to check outside the controller.